# Is there any way to get hindi / chinese text from image without specifying language in Tika Tesseract?

Tags: java, tesseract, apache-tika

Is there any way to get hindi / chinese text from image without specifying language in Tika Tesseract? Since i am trying to process images of different languages. Can't it detect the langauge by itself? For hindi I got this:
**`aol AIST GIR ak afer & AM A As
CaM SI GAMA WI Sl SS GS AR SRT
ol OF Utd S SR RE Se SIR & ua B sala
Peal dew |`**

Comment: Do you have the language pack for Tesseract for those languages installed?

Comment: I got all langues ( eng.traineedata, hin.traineedata, etc.)